# Как добавить символ перед каждым словом в строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить символ перед каждым словом в строке:

```
'python лучший язык'
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
'!python !лучший !язык'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
my_str = 'python лучший язык'
```

разделить строку на слова:

```
>>> my_str.split()
['python', 'лучший', 'язык']
```

добавить к каждому символ "!":

```
for word in my_str.split():
    print(f'!{word}')
```

выведет:

```
!python
!лучший
!язык
```

собрать в новую строку через пробел:

```
new_str = ' '.join(f'!{word}' for word in my_str.split())
```

теперь в new_str:

```
>>> new_str
'!python !лучший !язык'
```

Comment: `new_str = '!' + ' !'.join(my_str.split())`

Comment: `new_str = "!" + my_str.replace(" ", " !")`

Answer (score 2):

Регулярное выражение которое отыскивает начало слова `r'\b(?=\w)'`.

- `\b` - граница слова (и начало и конец);
- `\w` - символ из слова;
- cкобки `(?=...)` означают что соответствие должно быть но символы в строке менять не надо.

`re.sub` отыскивает все соответствия из заменяет их на `!`. Так как регулярное выражение в нашем случае совпадает с пустой строкой (указывает на место между символами), то это не замена, а вставка:

```
@>>> re.sub(r'\b(?=\w)', '!', 'python лучший язык')
'!python !лучший !язык'
```